# Using break in while loop is giving me error "break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch" even though it is already inside a loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, break

```
public class rps {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    int userCount = 0;
    int myCount = 0;
    int tieCount = 0; /* All 3 are counters that keep track of win scores */
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); /* Create a scanner */
    String play = ""; /* Scanner string local variable */   
do {    
    System.out.print("Please enter Play if you want to play the game or anything else to Stop");
    play = scan.nextLine(); // 
    }   
     while (play.equalsIgnoreCase("play")); {
        System.out.print("Choose your weapon [R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissors: ");
        String rps = scan.nextLine();
        while (rps.equals('R') || rps.equals('P') || rps.equals('S')) {
            System.out.println("You chose: " + rps);
        }
        int rand = (int)(Math.random() * 3);
        String myMove = "";
        if(rand == 0) {
            myMove = "Rock";
        }
        else if(rand == 1) {
            myMove = "Paper";
        }
        else {
            myMove = "Scissors";
        }
        System.out.println("I chose: " + myMove);
        
        
        if(rps.equals(myMove)) {
            System.out.println("Tie!");
            tieCount++;
        }
        else if(rps.equals('P') && myMove.equals('S')) {
            System.out.println("Scissors beats paper, a win for me!");
            myCount++;
        }
        else if(rps.equals('S') && myMove.equals('R')) {
            System.out.println("Rock beats scissors, a win for me!");
            myCount++;
        }
        else if(rps.equals('R') && myMove.equals('P')) {
            System.out.println("Paper beats rock, a win for me!");
            myCount++;
        }
        else if(rps.equals('S') && myMove.equals('P')) {
            System.out.println("Scissors beats paper, a win for you!");
            userCount++;
        }
        else if(rps.equals('R') && myMove.equals('S')) {
            System.out.println("Rock beats scissors, a win for you!");
            userCount++;
        }
        else if(rps.equals('S') && myMove.equals('P')) {
            System.out.println("Paper beats rock, a win for you!");
            userCount++;
        }
        
        System.out.println("Please enter Play if you want to play the game again or anything else to Stop.");
        if(!play.equalsIgnoreCase("play")) break;
    }
}
```

How can I make it so I can end the loop? It's giving me an error that it cannot be used outside of a loop but I am confused because it is still in my loop? I assume it is something to do with the fact that it is in a main method but without the main method I get a different error on the part of my scanner code. (I am supposed to make a rock paper scissors game that ends at the end of the loop when the user chooses to stop. I don't know how to go about fixing this error.)

Comment: You're messing up the `do...while`. After the `while`, you shouldn't start another block. Then of course the compiler tells you you can't break there, because that block is not the `while` body.

Comment: That makes sense but in the assignment the directions specifically said to validate the input using a while loop

Comment: You have a misplaced semicolon on your outermost while-loop: `while (play.equalsIgnoreCase("play")); {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to read a first value before looping. So do this :

```
    //do { // no need do
    System.out.print("Please enter Play if you want to play the game or anything else to Stop");
    play = scan.nextLine(); // 
   // } no need do

    while (play.equalsIgnoreCase("play")) { // remove comma here
        System.out.print("Choose your weapon [R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissors: ");
        S
```

Final code wil be :

```
    // these two lines allow to initialize "play" variable
    System.out.print("Please enter Play if you want to play the game or anything else to Stop");
    play = scan.nextLine();

    while (play.equalsIgnoreCase("play")) { // (**) test "play" var to keep in the loop
       // these 2 lines are good.
       System.out.print("Choose your weapon [R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissors: ");
       String rps = scan.nextLine();
        ...
        ...

        ...
        ...

        ...
        ...

        // at the end of the loop, read again "play" var to decides if you stay or stop loop
        System.out.println("Please enter Play if you want to play the game again or anything else to Stop.");
        play = scan.nextLine(); // IMPORTANT
        // but no need to break, because the play value will be tested by the enclosing while condition at (**)
        // if(!play.equalsIgnoreCase("play")) 
            // break;
    }
```

Comment: So you are saying I should delete the do loop? Will it make any difference to the code

Comment: Delete only the two lines I showed. You need the `system.print` and `play = scan` because **play** is tested in **while condition**

Comment: Ok. And I should put the ```system.print``` and ```play = scan``` outside of the while loop?

Comment: Not at all, wait 1 minute I update my answer as well

Comment: I have improved you algorithm

Answer (score 2):

The break is indeed outside the loop. Your loop is this:

```
do {    
    System.out.print("Please enter Play if you want to play the game or anything else to Stop");
    play = scan.nextLine(); // 
} while (play.equalsIgnoreCase("play"));
```

You probably meant your code to be like this:

```
 // no do {
System.out.print("Please enter Play if you want to play the game or anything else to Stop");
play = scan.nextLine(); // 
 // no }

while (play.equalsIgnoreCase("play")) { // no semicolon!
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

You seem to be confused by the two forms the while loop can take:

1. `do { <code> } while ( <condition> )` - here, the code comes before the condition and is always executed at least once.
2. `while ( <condition>) { <code> }` - here, the condition comes first, and the code might not be executed even once.

Your example should look something like this to work:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); /* Create a scanner */

while (true) {    
    System.out.print("Please enter Play if you want to play the game or anything else to Stop");
    String play = scan.nextLine();

    if (!play.equalsIgnoreCase("play")) {
        break();
    }

    System.out.print("Choose your weapon [R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissors: ");
    ...
}
```

Comment: So I don't need the "do" loop for it to work? I added it because originally I thought I would need it so the loop doesn't keep doing that even after the game ends

Answer (score 1):

Your `break` is actually not in a loop. You should have a look at the syntax of `do-while` loops. Then, you can realise that the loop ends after the semicolon after `while()`.

```
do {
    // Do some stuff in a loop...
}
while(condition);    // <-- Loop ends here
```

The relevant difference between a `while` loop and a `do-while` loop is that the former one is only entered when the given condition elevates to true while the latter one is always entered at least one.

### `while`

1. Check condition whether statement in loop should be executed
2. Execute statement in loop and go to beginning

### `do-while`

1. Execute statement in loop
2. Check condition to potentially start again.

Comment: So just to clarify, if I were to delete my do loop, would everything that was under it still show up every time the while loop breaks at the beginning of the "game"?

Comment: If you removed the `do {...}`, the situation would still be similar because the semicolon after `while()` ends the statement. If you also remove the semicolon, the `while` loop and the long list of statements will only be entered when the condition evaluates to `true` (I did not check the actual content/meaning of your code and therefore cannot asses whether it makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

You have a do-while loop.

```
do {    
           System.out.print("Please enter Play if you want to play 
                    the game or anything else to Stop");
           play = scan.nextLine(); // 
} while (play.equalsIgnoreCase("play"))
```

And you don't have a break within this loop.

Your `break` statement is out of loop. In short, you may need to learn how to use loop from a good book.